# Replacing target of symlink with newest subfolder using zOS script

Tags: symlink, mainframe, zos, jcl

Every time I deploy an agent on zOS server, a new subfolder is created under /usr/local/avi/ .

I manually change an existing symlink to that subfolder, the newest one, after each deployment.

I want to write a job that would check which is the newest subfolder under /usr/local/avi and update the symlink accordingly.

I have almost no knowledge of zOS.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to run that job manually, each time you did a new deploy? Or do sou wan the system to periodically check and recreate the symlink?

Comment: If the action could be triggered by a new subfolder creation (and not periodic check) under a specific folder it would be perfect. But a manual run is ok too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "... want to write a job...", are you talking about a z/OS batch job? If so, you can run prgram BPXBATCH to run the shell commands or shell script you would run manually on a shell session.

```
//jobname JOB CLASS=....  <== You need to adapt this JOB statement to fit your installations needs.
//STEP01   EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH
//STDOUT   DD   SYSOUT=*
//STDERR   DD   SYSOUT=*
//STDENV   DD   *
SYMLINK=sym-link-to-current-dir
DIRPREFIX=deployment-directory-prefix
/*
//STDPARM  DD   *
SH
  cd /target/directory ;                                         
  rm $SYMLINK ;                                             
  ln -s  $(ls -trd $DIRPREFIX* | tail -n 1)  $SYMLINK ;  
/*
```

Above commands assume that the name of the deployment directories have a common prefix. Adjust variable DIRPREFIX under //STDENV accordingly.
For convenience, the symlink name is also set as variable (SYMLINK).

**Note** The shell pipe symbol `|` is a variant character. That means the actual character to be typed in the TSO/ISPF session depends on the code page you're using. For example, I'm running with CP500 (Multinational), and I have to type an exclamation point `!` for the shell to see the `|`.

Running a batch job implies that you are allowed to `submit` the job, and that you are allowed to read the jobs output, e.g. via `SDSF` in your TSO/ISPF session.

There is no means to automatically detect directory creation and fire up some script, as far as I can tell.

Some details about the UNIX commands run:

1. The `cd /target/directory` should be self-explanatory
2. The `rm $SYMLINK` removes the symlink, so that it can be created again pointing the the new directory.
3. The next line `ln -s  $(ls -trd $DIRPREFIX* | tail -n 1)  $SYMLINK` creates a new symlink to the newest directory. In this line, the part `$(.....)` runs a subshell and returns the resulting output (stdout) back to the parent shell, which replaces the `$(.....)` with the result, and then continues to execute the command line.

The `ls -trd $DIRPREFIX*` lists the names of all matching directories (*1) and sorts the output by time (`-t`) in reverse order (`-r`), so that the newest directory will be listed in the last line. This output is then piped to the `tail -n 1` command which list only the last line (`-n 1`). This is line is then replacing the `$(.....)` to complete the `ln` utility.

(*1) Actually the `ls` lists all directory entries matching the `$DIRPREFIX*` operand, not only directories. But for the current problem, it is assumed that there are no other matching entries but (deployment) directory entries.

Comment: This job is a patch for a few weeks, until a reconfiguration of environment. Do you know how to find out which subfolder is the newest under a given folder in the batch job?

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the original question.  It certainly answers how to run a shell script in a batch job but not how to identify the newest folder and create a symlink.  All the detail seems to be missing from this "answer"